# contao theme installation issue . It shows could not find template

Tags: contao

I am trying to install Contao theme on my hosting account, but I am getting an error message and am unable to solve the issue.
I read the log file but unable to figure out what is the actual issue.
This is the error that I see in my browser: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jift.png)

These are the errors from my log file:

[2019-02-18 04:34:44] request.INFO: Matched route "contao_frontend". {"route":"contao_frontend","route_parameters":{"_route":"contao_frontend","_token_check":true,"_controller":"Contao\CoreBundle\Controller\FrontendController::indexAction","_scope":"frontend","alias":"home-3"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/contao-sample/web/home-3.html","method":"HEAD"} []
[2019-02-18 04:34:44] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2019-02-18 04:34:44] request.INFO: Matched route "contao_frontend". {"route":"contao_frontend","route_parameters":{"_route":"contao_frontend","_token_check":true,"_controller":"Contao\CoreBundle\Controller\FrontendController::indexAction","_scope":"frontend","alias":"home-3"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/contao-sample/web/home-3.html","method":"GET"} []
[2019-02-18 04:34:44] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2019-02-18 04:34:45] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "Could not find template "fe_page_extended"" at /opt/lampp/htdocs/contao-sample/vendor/contao/core-bundle/src/Resources/contao/library/Contao/TemplateLoader.php line 152 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Could not find template \"fe_page_extended\" at /opt/lampp/htdocs/contao-sample/vendor/contao/core-bundle/src/Resources/contao/library/Contao/TemplateLoader.php:152)"} []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that you are missing the template `fe_page_extended`, which you had selected in your page layout. May be you accidentally deleted it or missed it during a deployment. Simply edit your page layout(s) and save it again - or restore the missing template.